# DataTable - Pagination and Filter don't work for JavaScript generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have JavaScript generated table in DataTables, but pagination and filter don't show (work). When I tried to use *bFilter* or *bPaginate*, it didn't help me.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u7yhx9fL/9/)

```
var keywords = [["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4],["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4], ["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4],["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4],["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4]];
    
    function buildKeywordTableString(keywords){
      
      var dataSet = new Array();
                
      for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++){
          dataSet.push([keywords[i][0],keywords[i][1]]);    
            }
            
            var table =  $('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"></table>')
            .dataTable({
                "data": dataSet,
                "bFilter":true,
                "paging": true,
                "bPaginate":true,
                "columns": [
                    {"title": "Keyword"},
                    {"title": "F"}
                ]
            })[0].outerHTML;
            
            return table;
        }
    
    $("body").append(buildKeywordTableString(keywords));
    $("body").append(buildKeywordTableString(keywords));
```

Comment: You might wanna try to test an already developed solution for DataTable http://egobits.com/envato/datamanager/example.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting the table into the DOM first, and then initializing it as a DataTable. You'll also want to make sure you have a valid thead in the table too:

https://jsfiddle.net/u7yhx9fL/10/

```
var keywords = [["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4],["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4], ["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4],["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4],["dog", 2],["table", 3],["chair", 4]];
var id=0;

function buildKeywordTableString(keywords){

    var dataSet = new Array();
        
    for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++){
      dataSet.push([keywords[i][0],keywords[i][1]]);    
    }
    
    var table =  '<table id="table' + id + '" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"><thead><tr><th>Keyword</th><th>F</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>';
    $('body').append(table);
    $('#table' + id).dataTable({
        "data": dataSet,
        "bFilter":true,
        "paging": true,
        "bPaginate":true
    });
    
    id++
}

buildKeywordTableString(keywords);
buildKeywordTableString(keywords);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following attribute to your table: `data-order='[[ 0, "desc" ]]'` if you want to order the results in descending order otherwise, you can use `data-order='[[ 0, "aesc" ]]'` if you want to order the results in ascending order.

Example:

```js
DataEntry.DataTable = $("#tblViewList").DataTable({
    "data": DataEntry.DataSet,
    "columns": [
        { "data" : "DomainName" },
        { "data" : "SystemName" },
        { "data" : "UserName" },
        { "data" : "Id-1" },
        { "data" : "Id-2" }
    ],
    order: [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    destroy: true
});
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem of the question that's asked, this only helps with the ordering, and not the pagination and the filters, which is what is asked.